# Is "hedon" an adjecitve?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

I heard this line in a film's audio description:

> As Nick plays his guitar, he looks out into the audience and sees Tris is among the hedon throng.

This scene shows Nick playing guitar onstage and Tris standing in the an audience that is enjoying and bobbing to the music. From what I heard, I can't think of another word that might be what precedes "throng". But as far as I know, "hedon" is a rare word and not an adjective.

I am not sure if I heard it wrong. I am putting a [recording clyp](https://clyp.it/fj2bf101) here for context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Trish is amongst the *heaving* throng.

Heaving is an informal way of saying "very crowded" and a throng is a tightly packed crowd of people.  These two words are often used together. It is a cliché meaning a large and dense crowd.